# Vue.js, Как получить доступ к тегу на котором вызывается директива?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Нужно получить доступ к элементу (тегу) для которого вызывается метод frameShow, который вызывается директивой v-if. Это позволит получать атрибуты, родителей и потомков элемента.

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="a1" v-if="frameShow()">
    <div id="a2" v-if="frameShow()">
</div>
```

...

```
methods: {
    frameShow: function () {
        //id = a1 или a2
        return (id === "a1") ? true : false;
    },
}
```

Как, например, получить в методе frameShow id тега для которого вызывается этот метод, через директиву Vue.js

Comment: а зачем знать id? почему не передать в функцию параметр?

Comment: `id === "a1"`, в разный момент времени может быть разной. т.е. при первом вызове она будет null следовательно `id === null = false`, надеюсь ответил на ваш вопрос

Comment: нет не ответил. У тебя постоянный id в элементе, он не меняется никак, по крайней мере в предоставленном коде.

Comment: Нужно получить доступ к элементу (тегу) для которого вызывается метод frameShow, который вызывается директивой v-if. Это позволит получать атрибуты, родителей и потомков. id это пример.

Comment: У тебя ошибка в логике. Тебе не нужно получать атрибуты родителей и потомком, потому что у тебя уже есть vue компонент, в котором все нужные тебе данные должны быть и ты уже сам должен их расставлять так как нужно.

Comment: Тут ошибка при условии, что рендеринг страницы осуществляется через компоненты, но он не осуществляется через компоненты.

Comment: Тут ошибка в любом случае. Возможно стоит использовать что-то еще вместо vue.

Comment: Что значит "в vue идет ориентация на компоненты"

Answer (score 1):

Если отвечать на поставленный вопрос

> Как получить доступ к тегу, на котором вызывается директива `v-if`?

то ответ — **никак**.

Дело в том, что в момент вызова функции в директиве `v-if`, а правильнее сказать, 
в момент проверки логического выражения в директиве `v-if`, элемента еще не существует.
В результате проверки выражения будет решено, создать и добавить элемент или нет.

Ниже приведен пример, который показывает, 
первое, что проверка выражения в директиве `v-if` происходит раньше, чем построение элемента, 
и второе, что это каждый раз новый элемент.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: function() {
    return { isShown: false }
  },
  methods: {
    show: function () {
      console.log('show')
      return this.isShown
    },
    random: function () {
      console.log('random')
      return Math.random()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <button @click="isShown=!isShown">Show/Hide</button>
  <div v-if="show()" class="test">{{ random() }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем верно. Элемент существует, хотя бы потому, что именно у него стоит атрибутом `v-if`. Но доступа к нему действительно нет, так как в vue идет ориентация на компоненты.

Answer (score 0):

1. Либо передавать в функцию значение:

   ```
   <div id="a1" v-if="frameShow(1)">2222</div>
   <div id="a2" v-if="frameShow(2)">33333</div>

   frameShow: function (item) {
       return (item === 1) ? true : false; 
   },
   ```
2. Если собираетесь манипулировать отображаемыми данными в зависимости от класса или id , почему просто не использовать css ?